# Do you use an apostrophe for a group or institution name?

Tags: apostrophe

Say, if you're going to create a writers' group called The Writers Land (just made it up), will you add an apostrophe like this, "The Writers' Land"? It looks odd to me, but perhaps that's just me? Same with other things like an institution name: Would you say Writers Association or Writers' Association (when you're creating it)? Do readers prefer one or the other?

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/566744/does-parks-trust-need-an-apostrophe

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks! My concern is that the version without the apostrophe might sound incorrect to people. Or do people usually regard it as normal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it correct to say "I write children books" (not possessive case)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92362/is-it-correct-to-say-i-write-children-books-not-possessive-case) This contains actual examples of Writers Guilds as well as Writers' Guilds. You're safer including the apostrophe, but you're almost certain to offend some pedant. The choice is yours: somewhat less likely to attract flak vs more in line with the latest trends.

Comment: @thewritergirl "The Writers Land *[verb]* on Mars"?

Comment: If someone is paying you to write it, ask them how they want it. If not, do it any way you please. Punctuation is free play and nobody enforces any rules.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks for pointing that out! It's for myself that I was asking. I'll do the apostrophe-less version as I don't like its head poking out from the side.

Comment: @WeatherVane LOL. That's only possible if Elon Musk succeeds in his mission to colonize Mars!

I suppose in "The Writers Land" version (without Mars), the word "writers" is understood as an adjective rather than a plural noun (even though it technically is a noun)?

Comment: I'm surprised one one has mentioned Mother's Day...